# google maps api v3 cannot get info boxes to show on dynamically created polygons

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polygons

okay here is what i have . I'm using smarty to populate the coordinates, pulled from mysql, My little application draws over 300 polygons onto the uk map for county boundaries. I've manages to do that just fine and also colour them as i want. Now i have a problem i cant get any info boxes to show up.

A little more info, The reason for counties_zone is that some area have islands which break the polygon making a mess. so I've had to zone them to close the polygons properly.

the rest of my smarty variables should be pretty self explanatory.

```
<script>
var map;
var infoWindow;

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions={
        zoom: 6,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.049976288319, - 2.8110410026615),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'),
            mapOptions);

    var counties={
    };
{foreach $counties as $county => $area}
    {foreach $area as $zone => $coords}
    counties["{$county}_{$zone}"]=new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: [
        {foreach $coords as $coord}
                new google.maps.LatLng({$coord.0}, {$coord.1}),
        {/foreach}
        ],
        strokeColor: "#0000ff",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#{$coord.2}",
        fillOpacity: 0.6
    });
    counties["{$county}_{$zone}"].setMap(map);

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    google.maps.event.addListener(counties["{$county}_{$zone}"], 'click', showInfoCounty);

    {/foreach}
{/foreach}

}

function showInfoCounty(event) {
    var contentString="<b>County</b><br />";
    contentString+="County name";

    // thhis works.
    console.log(contentString);

    // this works
    this.setOptions({ fillColor: "#000000" });

    // this doesnt work.

    // Replace our Info Window's content and position
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
    infowindow.open(map);
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map` variable is undefined in the `showInfoCounty` routine.  Make it global (it is currently local to the initialize function, or at least the version of it you initialize is, there is a global one, but it isn't initialized).

Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example showing issue: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/qy8j6a37/)

Change:

```
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'),
        mapOptions);
```

To:

```
map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'),
        mapOptions);
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/qy8j6a37/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much i honestly didn't think it was going to be that very simple! i just need to position it now but thats the fun of it, i got stuck going around in circles!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so here is my final solution. I have taken on board your note about the scope and removed the extra function so the global scope is no longer an issue.

```
/**
This code snippet accepts an array as follows for each polygon.
Colour should really be moved up a county level.

county_1 [0]

        Zone [0]

            Points [0] [ lat, lng, colour ] (colour code without the prepended #
            Points [1] [ lat, lng, colour ]
            Points [2] [ lat, lng, colour ]

county_1 [0]

        Zone [0]

            Point [0] [ lat, lng, colour ]
            Point [1] [ lat, lng, colour ]
            Point [2] [ lat, lng, colour ]
etc...
etc...

**/

// Removed global vars.
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions={
        zoom: 6,
        center: { lat:54.049976288319, lng:-2.8110410026615 },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    // brought map back into local scope.
    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'),
            mapOptions);

    // Initialise counties for populating the polygons.
    var counties={
    };

// I use smarty so thats why the odd looking loop,
// you will likely need to modify this and the
// associated ($vars} to your own needs.
{foreach $counties as $county => $area}
    {foreach $area as $zone => $coords}
    counties["{$county}_{$zone}"]=new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: [
        {foreach $coords as $coord}
                new google.maps.LatLng({$coord.0}, {$coord.1}),
        {/foreach}
        ],
        strokeColor: "#0000ff",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#{$coord.2}",
        fillOpacity: 0.6
    });

    // polygon assign to map
    counties["{$county}_{$zone}"].setMap(map);

    // set your info window information to collect later.
    counties["{$county}_{$zone}"].set("Info", '{$county}');    

    // add a listner for the click.
    google.maps.event.addListener(counties["{$county}_{$zone}"], 'click', function(event) {

        // create the new info window.
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        // get the previously set data and set it into the new info window.
        infoWindow.setContent( counties["{$county}_{$zone}"].get("Info") );

        // open the info window.
        infoWindow.open(map);

        // position the window, open at the click position with event.latLng
        infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
    });

    {/foreach}
{/foreach}

}

// generate the map.
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

This is the result. [image: Visual of the script output.]